# How to map 2 Either values without tupled

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I need to take 2 values, each of them is `Either<Throwable, Any>` and combine them together (or to do anything else) if each of the values is `Right`.

For `arrow-kt 0.11.0` it was possible with `tupled`

```
tupled(
     "Hello".right(), 
     "Word".right()
).map { params ->
     println(params.a + params.b) //go to map ONLY IF a and b are always right
}
```

but since `arrow-kt 0.12` tupled is deprecated in favor of Kotlin's Pair and Triple and I can`t figure out how to achieve the same without` tupled`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Either.zip](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/zip.html)

```
"hello".right().zip("world".right()) { a, b -> a + b }
```